# Switch error in Flutter What should I do?

Tags: flutter, dart, switch-statement

I'm coding a Youtube clone using GetX in Flutter.
I use Switch to route with GetX BottomSheet, but it doesn't apply, but breaks the code to apply it.
It is the same code as in the related video.

Here's the code:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Obx(() {
        switch (RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]) {
          case RouteName.Home:
            return Home();
            break;
          case RouteName.Explore:
            return Explore();
            break;
          case RouteName.Subscribe:
            return Subscribe();
            break;
          case RouteName.Library:
            return Library();
            break;
          case RouteName.Add:
            break;
        }
        return Container();
      }),
```

````
enum RouteName { Home, Explore, Add, Subscribe, Library }

class AppController extends GetxService { 
  static AppController get to => Get.find();

  RxInt currentIndex = 0.obs;

  void changePageIndex(int index) {
    if (RouteName.values[index] == RouteName.Add) {
      _showBottomSheet();
    } else {
      currentIndex(index);
    }
  }

  void _showBottomSheet() {
    Get.bottomSheet(YoutubeBottomSheet());
  }
}```
````

Comment: Are you not getting any eeror on this line RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]?

Comment: @Diwyansh There were no errors in RouteName.values[controller.currentIndex.value]. Other Home(); or Explore(); works just fine.

Comment: Okay when app crashes is there any error in console?